# Reducing redundant code

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have this very easy functionality to find, toggle and remove classes from my html elements. The thing is that I find my self repeating the same code with just different name classes. I basically wrote the same method 9 times. I know that is you keep writing the same thing over and over again there is a more efficient way to do it. So I just wanted to see how could I make my code more effective.

I attached the piece of my code where i find myself repeating a lot. I have a tried a few ideas, but I only save like 2 lines of code.

```
// SECTION 5

$("body").on("tap", ".state1, .display-state1", function showState1() {
          $(".show-overlay").toggleClass("display-state1");
          $(".show-overlay").removeClass("display-state2");
          $(".show-overlay").removeClass("display-state3");
    });

$("body").on("tap", ".state2, .display-state2", function showState2() {
          $(".show-overlay").toggleClass("display-state2");
          $(".show-overlay").removeClass("display-state1");
          $(".show-overlay").removeClass("display-state3");
    });

$("body").on("tap", ".state3, .display-state3", function showState3() {
          $(".show-overlay").toggleClass("display-state3");
          $(".show-overlay").removeClass("display-state1");
          $(".show-overlay").removeClass("display-state2");
    });

// SECTION 8

$("body").on("tap", ".state-1, .display-state-1", function showSection8State1() {
          $(".show-overlay-big").toggleClass("display-state-1");
          $(".state-1-pdfs").children().toggleClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-2-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-3-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-4-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-5-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-6-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-7-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-8-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-9-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-2");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-3");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-4");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-5");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-6");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-7");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-8");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-9");
    });

$("body").on("tap", ".state-2, .display-state-2", function showSection8State2() {
          $(".show-overlay-big").toggleClass("display-state-2");
          $(".state-2-pdfs").children().toggleClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-1-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-3-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-4-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-5-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-6-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-7-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-8-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-9-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-1");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-3");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-4");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-5");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-6");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-7");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-8");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-9");
    });

$("body").on("tap", ".state-3, .display-state-3", function showSection8State3() {
          $(".show-overlay-big").toggleClass("display-state-3");
          $(".state-3-pdfs").children().toggleClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-2-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-1-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-4-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-5-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-6-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-7-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-8-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-9-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-2");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-1");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-4");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-5");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-6");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-7");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-8");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-9");
    });

$("body").on("tap", ".state-4, .display-state-4", function showSection8State4() {
          $(".show-overlay-big").toggleClass("display-state-4");
          $(".state-4-pdfs").children().toggleClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-2-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-3-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-1-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-5-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-6-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-7-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-8-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-9-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-2");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-3");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-1");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-5");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-6");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-7");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-8");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-9");
    });

$("body").on("tap", ".state-5, .display-state-5", function showSection8State5() {
          $(".show-overlay-big").toggleClass("display-state-5");
          $(".state-5-pdfs").children().toggleClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-2-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-3-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-4-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-1-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-6-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-7-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-8-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-9-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-2");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-3");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-4");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-1");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-6");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-7");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-8");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-9");
    });

$("body").on("tap", ".state-6, .display-state-6", function showSection8State6() {
          $(".show-overlay-big").toggleClass("display-state-6");
          $(".state-6-pdfs").children().toggleClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-2-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-3-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-4-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-5-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-1-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-7-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-8-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-9-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-2");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-3");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-4");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-5");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-1");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-7");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-8");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-9");
    });

$("body").on("tap", ".state-7, .display-state-7", function showSection8State7() {
          $(".show-overlay-big").toggleClass("display-state-7");
          $(".state-7-pdfs").children().toggleClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-2-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-3-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-4-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-5-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-6-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-1-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-8-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-9-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-2");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-3");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-4");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-5");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-6");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-1");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-8");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-9");
    });

$("body").on("tap", ".state-8, .display-state-8", function showSection8State8() {
          $(".show-overlay-big").toggleClass("display-state-8");
          $(".state-8-pdfs").children().toggleClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-2-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-3-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-4-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-5-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-6-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-7-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-1-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-9-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-2");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-3");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-4");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-5");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-6");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-7");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-1");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-9");
    });

$("body").on("tap", ".state-9, .display-state-9", function showSection8State9() {
          $(".show-overlay-big").toggleClass("display-state-9");
          $(".state-9-pdfs").children().toggleClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-2-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-3-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-4-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-5-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-6-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-7-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-8-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".state-1-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-2");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-3");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-4");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-5");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-6");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-7");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-8");
          $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-1");
    });
```

Comment: i think you would be better helped on the CodeReview stack exchange site

Comment: I've never tried it, but I'll give it a shot. Thanks

Comment: try `.removeClass("class1 class2 class3 class4 class_etc")` and `$(".classA, .classB, .classC, classETC")` how selector

Comment: Also no need to use the selector more than once:  `$('.show-overlay').toggleClass("display-state3").removeClass("display-state1").removeClass("display-state2");`.  Less overhead that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have classes of format `state-#-pdfs` where `#` is in the range [1,9]. If you want to affect a subset of these classes, let's say in range [5,9], you can iterate as such with a simple `for` loop:

```
var i;
for( i=5; i<=9; i++ )
{
    $("state-"+i+"-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
}
```

If your goal is to never target a dynamic subset of these classes, but rather will *always* target the same classes no matter what, then it may be better to modify your HTML and add the same class to all the elements. That way a single selector will target everything you want them to target. At the end of the day it depends on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some to get you started:

```
$("body").on("tap", ".state1, .display-state1", function showState1() {
    $(".show-overlay").toggleClass("display-state1").removeClass("display-state2 display-state3");
});
```

and

```
$("body").on("tap", ".state-1, .display-state-1", function showSection8State1() {
    $(".show-overlay-big").toggleClass("display-state-1");
    $(".state-1-pdfs,.state-2-pdfs,.state-3-pdfs,.state-4-pdfs,.state-5-pdfs,.state-6-pdfs,.state-7-pdfs,.state-8-pdfs,.state-9-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
    $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-2 display-state-3 display-state-4 display-state-5 display-state-6 display-state-7 display-state-8 display-state-9");
});
```

But this all looks a bit hinky. I have no doubt there is a better way to handle what you are doing, but impossible to tell without the associated HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You could do like that: https://jsfiddle.net/L2fqbr0f/

```
//variables of SECTION 5
var classes5 = ["display-state1", "display-state2", "display-state3"];

function showState(class_Name){
    for (i = 0; i < classes5.length; i++) {  
        if (classes5[i] == class_Name)
            $(".show-overlay").toggleClass(classes5[i]);
        else
            $(".show-overlay").removeClass(classes5[i]);
    }
}


//variables of SECTION 8
var stateElements8 = [".state-1-pdfs", ".state-2-pdfs", ".state-3-pdfs", ".state-4-pdfs", ".state-5-pdfs", ".state-6-pdfs", ".state-7-pdfs", ".state-8-pdfs", ".state-9-pdfs"];
var showOverlayBigElement8 = $(".show-overlay-big");
var showOverlayBigClasses8 = ["display-state-1", "display-state-2", "display-state-3", "display-state-4", "display-state-5", "display-state-6", "display-state-7", "display-state-8", "display-state-9"];

function showSection8State(showOverlayBigClassesParam, stateElement){

    //Changing showOverlayBigElement8 classes
    for (i = 0; i < showOverlayBigClasses8.length; i++) {  
        if (showOverlayBigClasses8[i] == showOverlayBigClassesParam)
            showOverlayBigElement8.toggleClass(showOverlayBigClasses8[i]);
        else
            showOverlayBigElement8.removeClass(showOverlayBigClasses8[i]);
    }

    //Changing stateElements
    for (i = 0; i < stateElements8.length; i++) {  
        if (stateElements8[i] == stateElement)
            $(""+stateElement).children().toggleClass("display-pdfs");
        else
            $(""+stateElement).children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
    }

}


// SECTION 5
$("body").on("tap", ".state1, .display-state1", showState("display-state1"));
$("body").on("tap", ".state2, .display-state2", showState("display-state2"));
$("body").on("tap", ".state3, .display-state3", showState("display-state3"));


// SECTION 8

$("body").on("tap", ".state-1, .display-state-1", showSection8State("display-state-1", ".state-1-pdfs"));
//...
$("body").on("tap", ".state-1, .display-state-1", showSection8State("display-state-9", ".state-9-pdfs"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start, you could probably reduce this further, but should give you an idea....I have not tested this, but should be close.

```
$("body").on("tap", function(){
    var x = $(this).class();
    switch(x) {
        //9,8,7
        case "state-9":
        case "display-state-9":
        case "state-8":
        case "display-state-8":
        case "state-7":
        case "display-state-7":
            showSectionToggle();
        break;
        //6,5,4
        case "state-6":
        case "display-state-6":
        case "state-5":
        case "display-state-5":
        case "state-4":
        case "display-state-4":
            showSectionRemove();
        break;
         //3
        case "state-3":
        case "display-state-3":
            showState3();
            showSectionRemove();
        break;
        //2
        case "state-2":
        case "display-state-2":
            showState2();
            showSectionRemove();
        break;
        //1
        case "state-1":
        case "display-state-1":
            showState1();
            showSectionRemove();

        break;
        default:
                return;
    } 
});
function showSectionToggle() {
    for(i=1; i<9; i++){
        $(".state-"+i+"-pdfs").children().toggleClass("display-pdfs");
        $(".show-overlay-big").toggleClass("display-state-"+i);
    }
};
function showSectionRemove() {
    for(i=1; i<9; i++){
        $(".state-"+i+"-pdfs").children().removeClass("display-pdfs");
        $(".show-overlay-big").removeClass("display-state-"+i);
    }
}
function showState1(){
    $(".show-overlay").toggleClass("display-state1");
    $(".show-overlay").removeClass("display-state2");
    $(".show-overlay").removeClass("display-state3");
}
function showState2(){
    $(".show-overlay").toggleClass("display-state2");
    $(".show-overlay").removeClass("display-state1");
    $(".show-overlay").removeClass("display-state3");
}
function showState3(){
    $(".show-overlay").toggleClass("display-state3");
    $(".show-overlay").removeClass("display-state1");
    $(".show-overlay").removeClass("display-state2");
}
```